# Python ConfigParser from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I try to load config from file with read

But when it reads from same folder it works

When I read from parent it doesn’t.

Code:

```
/
config.ini
Conf/
    __init__.py
    config.ini
    Conf.py
```

// Conf.py

```
config = ConfigParser()

#this works
config.read(‘config.ini’)

#this doesn’t 
config.read(‘./../config.ini’)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these being executed in the same path? `./../config.ini` goes up a directory. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: please watch your quote chars in the code sample

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the same thing here, and both work:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

#this works
print(config.read('config.ini'))

#this works too
print(config.read('./../config.ini'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my question in the end:

```
import configparser
import os.path

conf = configparser.ConfigParser()

conf.read(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/../config.ini')
```